# How to sync change in global variable across multiple mappers in hadoop using java?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to keep count of number of tuples encountered so i used a global variable and incremented it every time I ran a mapper. I want to know that how different mappers sync that global variable as it is giving correct answer? I also want to know if this routine forces mappers to run sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `hadoop streaming`, you shouldn't do this.

> When an executable is specified for mappers, each mapper task will launch the executable as a **separate process** when the mapper is initialized. As the mapper task runs, it converts its inputs into lines and feed the lines to the stdin of the process. In the meantime, the mapper collects the line oriented outputs from the stdout of the process and converts each line into a key/value pair, which is collected as the output of the mapper.

Both the `mapper` and the `reducer` are executables that *read the input from stdin* (line by line) and *emit the output to stdout*.

[more about hadoop streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#Hadoop+Streaming)